# How to use a button to point to an existing url

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django, here i've to point a button to an existing url

```
<form> <input type="button" value="Put Your Text Here" onclick="window.location.href='/polls/{{ question.id }}/results/'" />
</form>
```

here i've created a button that points to a perticular url. is there any oprtimized methods available?

Comment: A <button> doesn't point to a url. If it's a submit button (as you made it), it usually submits a <form>. Where's your form? What do you want to submit? Apart from that, you should reverse urls in Django instead of hard-coding them. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls). In a template, you would use `{% url "polls:results" question_id=some_id %}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'detail' question_id=question.pk">
        {{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
        <button type='submit'> Result
        </button>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: <form>
<input type="button" value="Put Your Text Here" onclick="window.location.href='/polls/{{ question.id }}/results/'" />
</form>  i'm using like this any good methods?

Comment: @navaneethkt: please do not construct URLs yourself. If you later change one of the urls, then it will no longer point to a real link.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<li><a href="/polls/{{ question.question_id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li><a href="/polls/{{ question.question_id }}/results/" title="{{ question }} Results"><button type='submit'> Result</button></a>
```